# module 'networkx' has no attribute 'read_gpickle'

Tags: python, networkx, pickle

I'm trying to run this code that uses networkx to read a graph pickle file.

```
def read_graph(self, path=f'./dblp_graph.gpickle'):
    self.g = networkx.read_gpickle(path=path)
    return self.g
```

When I run this code using the Jupyter notebook I got following error:

> module 'networkx' has no attribute 'read_gpickle'

Then, using [THIS](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-2.5/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle.html) document I test networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle instead and got this error.

> module 'networkx.readwrite' has no attribute 'gpickle'

I also tried:

```
print(dir(nx.readwrite))
```

and the result is:

> ['GraphMLReader', 'GraphMLWriter', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**', 'adjacency', 'adjacency_data', 'adjacency_graph', 'adjlist', 'cytoscape', 'cytoscape_data', 'cytoscape_graph', 'edgelist', 'forest_str', 'from_graph6_bytes', 'from_sparse6_bytes', 'generate_adjlist', 'generate_edgelist', 'generate_gexf', 'generate_gml', 'generate_graphml', 'generate_multiline_adjlist', 'generate_network_text', 'generate_pajek', 'gexf', 'gml', 'graph6', 'graphml', 'json_graph', 'leda', 'multiline_adjlist', 'node_link', 'node_link_data', 'node_link_graph', 'pajek', 'parse_adjlist', 'parse_edgelist', 'parse_gml', 'parse_graphml', 'parse_leda', 'parse_multiline_adjlist', 'parse_pajek', 'read_adjlist', 'read_edgelist', 'read_gexf', 'read_gml', 'read_graph6', 'read_graphml', 'read_leda', 'read_multiline_adjlist', 'read_pajek', 'read_sparse6', 'read_weighted_edgelist', 'relabel_gexf_graph', 'sparse6', 'text', 'to_graph6_bytes', 'to_sparse6_bytes', 'tree', 'tree_data', 'tree_graph', 'write_adjlist', 'write_edgelist', 'write_gexf', 'write_gml', 'write_graph6', 'write_graphml', 'write_graphml_lxml', 'write_graphml_xml', 'write_multiline_adjlist', 'write_network_text', 'write_pajek', 'write_sparse6', 'write_weighted_edgelist']

So, there is no function to read/write pickle files!

P.s: I also forced jupyter to use networkx version 2.5 using "!pip3 install networkx==2.5" but there is no difference.

Comment: `read_gpickle` and `write_gpickle` were [removed](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_2.x_to_3.0.html#deprecated-code) in 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Migration Guide from 2.x to 3.0](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_2.x_to_3.0.html#deprecated-code):

> The functions `read_gpickle` and `write_gpickle` were removed in 3.0. You
> can read and write NetworkX graphs as Python pickles.

```
import pickle
G = nx.path_graph(4)

with open('test.gpickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(G, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

and to read a pickle:

```
with open('test.gpickle', 'rb') as f:
    G = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

In networkx last version, this way to write graphs has dissapeared.
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html#
Here the actual options.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)